# Removing column header from output

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I am running following command and output is shown below

and nova list

```
 +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name                                                                | cidr           | allocation_pools                                 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1865fd7d-8971-4b2a-aaa3-c810189c2363 | test-inter-netwk                                                    | 192.168.1.0/24 | {"start": "192.168.1.2", "end": "192.168.1.254"} |
| 20214812-48f9-4938-bbd3-1b54cd796425 | App-Mgmt-subnet                                                     | 10.20.0.0/24   | {"start": "10.20.0.2", "end": "10.20.0.254"}     |
| 7ab22397-e6a9-4a3d-96f0-9ebbce638f1e | vms2.1-net                                                          | 192.168.0.0/24 | {"start": "192.168.0.2", "end": "192.168.0.254"} |
| 8f97fc5e-53c6-4f29-9e4e-04f38a283452 | ddddd                                                               | 10.24.0.0/24   | {"start": "10.24.0.2", "end": "10.24.0.254"}     |
| 990b338c-c980-456e-ade1-fc1a90f233e5 | Orch-Mgmt-subnet                                                    | 10.32.1.0/24   | {"start": "10.32.1.2", "end": "10.32.1.254"}     |
| f386aca1-4c18-4b8e-9df7-a70111dea849 | TRANSIT-NEXTIP-Skyfall-eb07721aa407423e83e9641855f51e35-mseg-SUBNET | 10.22.0.0/24   | {"start": "10.22.0.2", "end": "10.22.0.254"}     |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Command

```
neutron subnet-list | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'
```

Output
output starts with two empty line and the text "id" and empty line.I need only id I am struggling to remove first few line.

```
 id

 1865fd7d-8971-4b2a-aaa3-c810189c2363
 20214812-48f9-4938-bbd3-1b54cd796425
 7ab22397-e6a9-4a3d-96f0-9ebbce638f1e
 8f97fc5e-53c6-4f29-9e4e-04f38a283452
 990b338c-c980-456e-ade1-fc1a90f233e5
 f386aca1-4c18-4b8e-9df7-a70111dea849
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed to print only lins that match (-n option and p at the end).
Look for a match at the beginning of the line, right after `|`.
Search for a string starting with at least 3 non-spaces (skipping `ip` but perhaps a problem with other neutron output) using `[^ ]\{3\}`.
Add the next characters until a space in the string to be remembered in `\(..\)`.
Throw away the remaining characters with `.*`.
Put back the first (and only) remembered string with `\1`.

```
neutron subnet-list |sed -n 's/^| \([^ ]\{3\}[^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a conditional to your awk statement:

```
neutron subnet-list | awk -F "|" 'NR>2{print $2}'
```

That just says "IF the Record Number (`NR`) is greater than 2, then go ahead and print.

---

If you want to remove the blank after the `id` you could add that:

```
neutron subnet-list | awk -F "|" 'NR>2 && NR!=4{print $2}'
```

Which adds to the first conditional " And Record Number is not 4"

---

You could also just strip out any blank `$2` fields to keep it simple:

```
neutron subnet-list | awk -F "|" '$2!=""{print $2}'
```